# JPEG Encoding question

Tags: encoding, jpeg

24 bits are available per pixel. 
Assuming
1. eyes are sensitive to brightness than color.
2. eyes are sensitive to red & green than blue.

What kind of encoding can I choose?

I thought about it,but didn't get an idea. Y'CbCr with 4:2:0 encoding works for the brightness part, but what about the color?

Comment: I thought that Y'CbCr with 4:2:0 is part of YUV specs.

Answer (score 0):

That's already accounted for. YUV420 meens that the color components are subsampled. I'm not sure if it was horizontally or vertically though. That means that your image will contain half the color information compared to luminence. Also, the quantization tables are different for the color components so that will also increase the compression rate.